# В alpine linux не выполняются бинарные файлы

Tags: golang, docker

Устанавливаю в docker-in-docker golang. Но не могу выполнить его:

```
FROM docker:19.03.12
RUN apk add git make
RUN wget https://golang.org/dl/go1.15.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz && tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.15.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz
RUN tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.15.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz
ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
RUN echo ${PATH}
CMD go version
```

В чём проблема, как решить?

Ошибка: `go not found`

Comment: А какое сообщение об ошибке было?

Answer (score 3):

Необходимо добавить библиотеку `libc6-compat`. Тогда получим рабочее решение:

```
FROM docker:19.03.12
RUN apk add git make libc6-compat
RUN wget https://golang.org/dl/go1.15.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz && tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.15.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz
RUN tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.15.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz
ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
RUN echo ${PATH}
CMD go version
```